# Usar django-smart-selects en django 2.2.4

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls, python-3.7, django-smart-selects

Hola he buscado la manera de acomplar o de econtrar una librerira que me permita hacer lo que realiza django-smart-selects, ya que no puedo utilizarla en django 2.2. en adelante, actualmente estoy trabajando e intentando en django 2.2.4 sin emgargo me encuentro col los mismos errores. tengo agregado `smart-selects` en mi `settings.py` y este es mi `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
    ]
```

tengo agregado el `JQUERY_URL = True` en el `settings.py` pero me lanza este error...!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Este es el ***Traceback***:

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/core/location/add/

Django Version: 2.2.4
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'smart_selects',
 'core']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\base.html, error at line 3
   'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith'
   1 : {% load i18n static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
   2 : {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}{% get_current_language_bidi as LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
   3 : <html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"en-us" }}" {% if LANGUAGE_BI DI %}dir="r tl"{% endif %}>
   4 : <head>
   5 : <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
   6 : <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">
   7 : {% block extrastyle %}{% endblock %}
   8 : {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet_rtl %}{% static "admin/css/rtl.css" %}{% endblock %}">{% endif %}
   9 : {% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}
   10 : {% block responsive %}
   11 :     <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
   12 :     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/responsive.css" %}">
   13 :     {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/responsive_rtl.css" %}">{% endif %}


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  145.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  143.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  993.         return render_value_in_context(output, context)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_value_in_context
  972.             value = str(value)

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py" in <lambda>
  388.     klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in __str__
  63.         return self.render()

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in render
  78.         return mark_safe('\n'.join(chain.from_iterable(getattr(self, 'render_' + name)() for name in MEDIA_TYPES)))

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in <genexpr>
  78.         return mark_safe('\n'.join(chain.from_iterable(getattr(self, 'render_' + name)() for name in MEDIA_TYPES)))

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in render_js
  85.             ) for path in self._js

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in <listcomp>
  85.             ) for path in self._js

File "C:\Users\kapal\Envs\pruebasmselects\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in absolute_path
  105.         if path.startswith(('http://', 'https://', '/')):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/core/location/add/
Exception Value: 'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

y cuando quito el `JQUERY_URL = True` en el `settings.py` y agrego `USE_DJANGO_JQUERY = True`, `USE_DJANGO_JQUERY = False`, `USE_DJANGO_JQUERY = None`, me carga pero no me muestra el campo encadenado, exactamente asi..!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda ya no encuentro que hacer y la verdad no se si existe otra solucion mas practica o alguien que me pueda guiar en la configuracion correcta de `django-smart-selects`

Exactamente esta es la funcionalidad que necesito de djnago smart selects que segun el padre me muestre los datos que corresponden unicamente a este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda ya no encuentro que hacer y la verdad no se si existe otra solucion mas practica o alguien que me pueda guiar en la configuracion correcta de django-smart-selects

Exactamente esta es la funcionalidad que necesito de djnago smart selects que segun el padre me muestre los datos que corresponden unicamente a este.

Comment: Que funcionalidad exactamente requieres de este complemento? En mi experiencia con Django no he necesitado algo que me haga llegar a este. Quizas exista otra forma de lograrlo que no implique utilizar una librería que no tiene soporte hace más de 1 año.

Comment: Si gracias en si lo que realiza django-smart-selects es poder mostrar campos encadenados inteligentemente, es decir un ejemplo clasico es el de su documentacion..! en donde si tienes un continente por ejemplo america: tiene paises por ejemplo mexico: y este tiene estados: ejemplo monterey, DF etc, Lo que hace en si es que cuando tu en el campo padre escoges Mexico, solo te devuelva los estados de Mexico y no todos los estados que estan registrados.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración. El stacktrace que te lanza el front-end en incompleto, intenta enviar siempre el stacktrace completo que lanza la consola que está ejecutando el manage.py. Ahora, el comportamiento que necesitas es sólo para la vista de admini?

Comment: Gracias amigo, ya actualice la app me seria de mucha utlidad poder resolver esta duda tengo aproximadamente mas de 6 meses buscando una solucion y no encuentro ninguna.